# "Android For Work" API on emulator

Tags: android

I created android 5.0 emulator using Android
SDK (google api intel x86 atom_64 image).
Power on the emulator, go to settings/security,
click "Encrypt Phone", it just reboot the
emulator, no encryption ever happen.
But I was able to encrypt 4.4 Emulator, so I am
wondering if "Encrypt Phone" still works on 5.0
+ Emulator. If not, how to use the new
"Android For Work" API on emulator?